# updating php version on mac 10.5.8

Tags: php, macos

Im trying to run a CMS system on a Macbook version 10.5.8, so pretty old.
The CMS is saying it requires PHP version 5.3.2 or higher. I am wondering how I update the PHP version? I have downloaded the version but do not know what to do with the folder once its unzipped.

Any help would be great, Im more PC than Mac

Answer (score 0):

You might try installing XAMPP for Mac: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html -- which only needs OS 10.4. FYI, launch terminal & enter `php -v` to see the current PHP version. Mac OS doesn't come with built in MYSQL, so you'll need something like XAMPP anyway to run your CMS.

I use MAMP myself, but that requires OS 10.6.x

Comment: yeah I had the version problem with MAMP and have already turned to XAMPP. The problem is that Ive added the CMS (silverstripe) folder to the XAMPP directory and when I run the CMS it says my PHP version needs updating.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how I can update my version of PHP?? cheers for the response btw

Comment: that's too bad. can you check the php version? if XAMPP works, make a file that just has <?php phpinfo();?> and run it, should give you version. Since XAMPP is put out by Apache, I assumed it would give you a fairly new PHP. According to silverstripe site, you only need PHP 5.3.2+